# Got two reputation points, twice, for accepting an answer

Tags: support, reputation

I accepted an answer for [my question on Web Application Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/55359/53090) and if I am not wrong you get two reputation points for doing that. But I got it *twice*. Once yesterday and once today.

[image: screen shot]

Why was I given two additional reputation points? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

You got [2 rep points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/53090/naveen?tab=reputation) for accepting & 2 more for suggesting an edit that was approved. That's by design.

Comment: Man... probably the stupidest question I have asked. After 2k reputation points on Stack Overflow I never got points for editing leading to this *short term* memory loss!

Comment: happens, occasionally :)